# Access IBM MQ Remotely

Tags: java, ibm-mq

When I try to access IBM MQ remotely, I get the errors below in my log file. Could someone give me some tip about what could I do to solve this?

```
AMQ5534E: the authentication user id usermq failed. 

AMQ5542I: The authentication verification with fail was caused by configuration CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT (RECDADMIN) of queue manager.
```

I asked my network administrator to create another user for me to make the access, but didn't solve.

Comment: Did you set the authority for that user on the queue manager?
The following link provides more information about similar error.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680930

Comment: it can connect and ask for information by default. I added the authority to show and alter, but didn't solve.

Comment: Do I need to include remote queue manager? isn't enough just to create a queue manager, it's queue and channel?

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680930